# How to create/connect to localdb using VS Code

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-code, localdb

I want to know if there is a way to create or connect to a localdb like you do in Visual Studio.
I had explored the extension **mssql** which was mentioned here :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/visual-studio-code/sql-server-develop-use-vscode?view=sql-server-ver16.

Correct me if I am wrong, this is only applicable if you have sql express / sql server installed.

Comment: Yes, you need sql express.

Comment: You need to [install LocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver16#install-localdb)

Comment: This link is very helpful. Thank you @Squirrel!